# Find out ESRI REST URL for web map which is hiding it

Tags: geojson, web-mapping, rest

I would like to extract the pipeline geometries from https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=a00c3b5cee4e4fe0b238b5e05ed80204

It shows the existing gas & oil pipelines crossing through Pennsylvania and was created by FracTracker for http://www.roverpipelinefacts.com/about/route.html . Despite it's a NGO they don't allow you downloading their data.

If I should know the REST FeatureServer URL I could download it (EXAMPLE):

```
wget "https://services.arcgis.com/jDGuO8tYggdCCnUJ/arcgis/rest/services/AtlanticCoastPipeline/FeatureServer/2/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=geojson"
```

How can I find out this URL for the web map from above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST service for the existing pipelines is https://services.arcgis.com/jDGuO8tYggdCCnUJ/arcgis/rest/services/Esisting_pipelines_final_updated/FeatureServer/0

But am I right that you are more interested in the proposed ones? The existing US pipeline network can be downloaded from EIA: https://www.eia.gov/maps/layer_info-m.php

The proposed pipelines layer seems to be somehow disables, I'm not sure whether you could guess the URL.

Edit:

The pipelines are here

http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=http://services.arcgis.com/jDGuO8tYggdCCnUJ/ArcGIS/rest/services/Buckeye_Partners_Pipeline_Proposal/FeatureServer

http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=http://services.arcgis.com/jDGuO8tYggdCCnUJ/ArcGIS/rest/services/Pennsylvania_and_New_York_SXL_and_Kinder_Morgan_Proposals/FeatureServer

Answer (score 4):

I found the URL:
https://services.arcgis.com/jDGuO8tYggdCCnUJ/ArcGIS/rest/services/Esisting_pipelines_final_updated/FeatureServer

by going into developer tools in Chrome: F12 and reloading the site and watching the network tab.:
[image]

And you can remove resources from the url to get other services:
https://services.arcgis.com/jDGuO8tYggdCCnUJ/ArcGIS/rest/services

You can do the same thing with Fiddler--I use both, but the browser dev tools are usually sufficient for casual inspection.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the webmap, and click on the "..." under the layer (i.e. more options) you can see the attached AGOL metadata (https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a2bd08552ba54a3899ffc53b747b22e8), which provides a service URL for the existing;

https://services.arcgis.com/jDGuO8tYggdCCnUJ/arcgis/rest/services/Esisting_pipelines_final_updated/FeatureServer/0

It doesn't look like the "proposed metadata" (and service url) are being provided.

Using the network response request is also another way to find the same information.