# Extracting ArcGIS REST Server from Webmap URL

Tags: wms, wfs, arcgis-rest-api, url, arcgis-online-webmap

I would like to view certain Webmap information in my desktop GIS software, and I'm looking for a way to extract a REST server (or, in future situations, WMS/WFS/WCS URLs) from a webmap website.

I reviewed these two posts:

- [Find out ESRI REST URL for web map which is hiding it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297267/find-out-esri-rest-url-for-web-map-which-is-hiding-it)
- [Adding ArcGIS webappviewer to QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421179/adding-arcgis-webappviewer-to-qgis)

It's clear that you need to inspect the website/use developer tools to find the feature service URL from the Network Tab... and this is where I run into problems. For example, I'm trying to get the REST URL for this website https://tpwd.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=f5e8debeaa994abe888d86a7112649ff. But when I analyze the network tab, I can't find the REST server URL.

How do I find this URL using inspect element?

See picture below:

[image: picture GCWA]

Comment: search 'query?' on the network tab on your inspect element. [check this out](https://services1.arcgis.com/1mtXwieMId59thmg/arcgis/rest/services/BCP_Current_Boundary/FeatureServer/), it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is get the application's configuration. Do this by searching the Network tab in the browser's Developer Tools.

If you filter on `f5e` for instance (which is part of the ID in your URL), you will find a request to the Web Mapping Application: https://tpwd.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/f5e8debeaa994abe888d86a7112649ff/data?f=json

The response is a JSON file which has a `map` attribute that in turn has an `ItemID` of `ef0d5fe1a5f841ffb432445b1913cb55`:

[image: Web Mapping Application JSON]

Now, search the Network tab for that ID. You will find two items, you need this one: https://tpwd.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/ef0d5fe1a5f841ffb432445b1913cb55/data?f=json

This is also a JSON file, of the Web Map this time, containing all used layers and basemaps.

[image: Web Map JSON]

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful, however I haven't been able to add the map to my QGIS. I find the area that you're talking about, and I successfully reach a REST server page when I search for the URL from layer 0 "GCWA_2016HabClass_3319". However, when the layer does not display after it's added to my map. Is this ia security/access view, or is there another step I have to complete in order to see map?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about qgis. You might ask a separate question about that .

Comment: Okay no worries, and thank you for your help. I realize that that was not specified in the original question, so a new post would be best.